# Como hacer User Control de Navegacion?

Tags: c#, wpf

Hola estoy haciendo una aplicacion WPF y necesito algun UserControl que me permita mostrar informacion y navegar entre paginas como se muestra a continuacion. Quiciera saber si hay alguno ya hecho.
[image: Como quiciera que quedara mi UserControl]

Comment: Hola! lo que estas pidiendo no esta bien visto en este sitio. Mira https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para saber como funcionamos. Saludos!

Comment: Y porque no creas tu propio control?